# Inline in Django admin: has no ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I have two Django models:

```python
class Author(models.Model):
    user_email =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    display_name =  models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Photo(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    image = ThumbnailImageField(upload_to='photos')
```

To get inline photos, I have in admin.py:

```python
class PhotoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Author

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('display_name','user_email')
    inlines = [PhotoInline]
```

I get an error: `Exception at /admin/metainf/author/11/`

```
<class 'metainf.models.Author'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'metainf.models.Author'>
```

Why?

Answer (score 23):

The inline model should be having a ForeignKey to the parent model. To get `Photo` as inline in `Author` your models code is fine. But your admin code should be as follows:

```
class PhotoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Photo

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('display_name','user_email')
    inlines = [PhotoInline]
```

Read more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Answer (score 4):

That's because `Author` doesn't have a foreign key to photo. I think you need to switch the model for the inline like this:

```
class PhotoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Photo

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('display_name','user_email')
    inlines = [PhotoInline]
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to install django-nested-admin library, and later try with NestedStackedInline. 
[django-nested-admin](https://pypi.org/project/django-nested-admin/)